# Using DrawRect draw a circle the same physical size on iPad or iPad mini

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, drawing, drawrect

I have read there is no future-proof programmatic way to detect iPad Mini vs iPad.  But do you have a solution to this:  without knowing the device draw a circle the same physical size across any iOS device?  I feel like I should know this /be able to do this, but I have never run across the requirement before.